# Angular UI Grid - reload data not working

Tags: angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am using ui-grid. The left panel has search filters and a search button which populates data into grid in right panel (initially grid renders without data). Application has two separate controller one for search panel and another for grid.
Now i am using shared service to pass data from searchController to gridController but data in grid is not displaying. I can see gridOptions.data is set by that function. 
console.log( $scope.gridOptions.data)//length is 2 here.
If i tried to call http.get directly from grid controller and bind data in success object, grid populates properly.

I tried different methods to refresh/reload (see below) the grid but no results.
$scope.gridApi.core.refresh();

Any suggestion.

Comment: Can you please do a plunker for it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign data to $scope.gridOptions.data  in your grid controller.

I assume, you are getting that data from your shared service.

Also ensure, search button generates an event which fetches data from shared service, and assigns it.